# Windows 10 - Failed at the @angular/cli@8.2.2 postinstall script

Tags: windows, npm, angular-cli, npm-install

I cannot get Angular CLI installed on a new Windows 10 machine at all.

I have cleared node cache. I have uninstalled and re-installed node via every method including chocolatey. I have edited the npmrc to change the default location of node modules... everything I can find

`$ npm install @angular/cli`

> @angular/cli@8.2.2 postinstall C:\sandbox\ang\node_modules@angular\cli
>   node ./bin/postinstall/script.js

```
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\sandbox\ang\package.json'
npm WARN ang No description
npm WARN ang No repository field.
npm WARN ang No README data
npm WARN ang No license field.

npm ERR! file C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;
npm ERR! path C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;
npm ERR! @angular/cli@8.2.2 postinstall: `node ./bin/postinstall/script.js`
npm ERR! spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe; ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @angular/cli@8.2.2 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\tblaw\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-16T01_04_13_709Z-debug.log
```

Comment: I have done npm init and confirmed a package.json as well. ENOENT error

Comment: The code mentions a complete log of the run at `C:\Users\tblaw\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-16T01_04_13_709Z-debug.log`. Could you provide that file?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the latest node installed? I though I did, but I had separate versions installed via homebrew (which had the latest 12.10), and globally only had 6.5.
Test with `node -v` and force latest version with `nvm install 12.0.0`